# Pandas - Create df from list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have data in the following format (list of dicts that each contain a list of 3 lists):

```
[{40258: [['2018-07-03T14:13:41'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
 {40257: [['2018-07-03T13:47:55',
    '2018-07-03T14:21:52',
    '2018-07-04T11:56:44'],
   ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party'],
   ['In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party', 'In Progress']]},
 {40255: [['2018-07-03T13:12:58'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
 {40250: [[], [], []]}]
```

I would like the above to be converted to the following df:

```
key    List1-1              List1-2            List1-3               List2-1     List2-2          List2-3                 List3-1         List3-2                   List3-3
40258  2018-07-03T14:13:41  nan                nan                   'Open'      nan              nan                     'Closed'        nan                       nan
40257  2018-07-03T13:47:55 2018-07-03T14:21:52 2018-07-04T11:56:44   'Open'     'In Progress'    'Waiting on 3rd Party'   'In Progress'   'Waiting on 3rd Party'   'In Progress'
40255  2018-07-03T13:12:58  nan                nan                   'Open'      nan              nan                     'Closed'        nan                       nan
40250  nan                  nan                nan                    nan        nan              nan                      nan            nan                       nan
```

- Each key is a row and each element of the list is a column.
- The outer list contains 50,000 dict's to be made into rows.
- There are always exactly 3 inner lists.
- The inner lists are of variable length - ranging from 0 up to a maximum of 25.

I have tried a plain `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` but I can't find solutions that deal with multiple lists inside the dict.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i am wondering about why all the dicts? Wouldn't it be easier if you first cleaned up the inputdata you are getting. When you will receive your data in this way I can see some issues popping up which force you to get creative when building/filling your dataframe. I presume you are filling statusupdates on some sort of tickets, where the key is the ticketnumber. Make a dataframe with 3 columns, and fill that with the actions a ticket went through (eg.: you would have to split up dict 40257). That would save you a lot of pointless columns in your dataframe.

Comment: You are correct re: ticket statuses. I did also have a similar thought about the structure and I do have control over the structure of how I receive this data. I structured it like this as I have to do further calculations between each data point - such as time between two 'transitions' (Date2 - Date1 in 40257). I'm all ears for a better way but don't quite understand how only 3 columns would suffice. Thanks

Comment: from what i can see the structure currently is: itemnumber(dictkey), date(first item list), and 2 times a status (i presume the current status and the previous status, to track the change?). I you add just a single entry into your data for each event that happens with a ticket, you can later on easily filter out what happened with each item. Your headers would look something like ('ticket','date','current status','previous status'). Which makes 4 columns, missed on previously ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data=[{40258: [['2018-07-03T14:13:41'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
 {40257: [['2018-07-03T13:47:55',
     '2018-07-03T14:21:52',
     '2018-07-04T11:56:44'],
    ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party'],
    ['In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party', 'In Progress']]},
  {40255: [['2018-07-03T13:12:58'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
  {40250: [[], [], []]}]

f = lambda x: x + [np.nan]*(3-len(x))
mod_data = [ [k]+ sum(list(map(f, v)), []) for d in data for k,v in d.items()]

cols = ['key', 'List1-1', 'List1-2', 'List1-3', 'List2-1', 'List2-2', 'List2-3', 'List3-1', 'List3-2', 'List3-3']
df = pd.DataFrame(mod_data, columns=cols).set_index('key')
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
                   List1-1              List1-2              List1-3 List2-1      List2-2               List2-3      List3-1               List3-2      List3-3
key                                                                                                                                                            
40258  2018-07-03T14:13:41                  NaN                  NaN    Open          NaN                   NaN       Closed                   NaN          NaN
40257  2018-07-03T13:47:55  2018-07-03T14:21:52  2018-07-04T11:56:44    Open  In Progress  Waiting on 3rd Party  In Progress  Waiting on 3rd Party  In Progress
40255  2018-07-03T13:12:58                  NaN                  NaN    Open          NaN                   NaN       Closed                   NaN          NaN
40250                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN     NaN          NaN                   NaN          NaN                   NaN          NaN
```

Comment: This is awesome, well done. It works great!
Do you happen to know how I would find the longest number of elements in my data so that I can automate the creation of column names?
Ex. I would search all lists in all dicts and return 3. (If not I can always create a new question). Thanks again!

Comment: You have to navigate it atleast once to find the length of longest element.
Something like this might work `max([len(e) for d in data for k,v in d.items() for e in v])`

Comment: If I could upvote 10x I would, works great. Thank you.

Comment: Totally. Me too.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a list of lists and then create a df using pd.dataFrame(data,columns) is what seems the easiest option.

```
# First calculate the length of maximum list in the dictionary
# Let that be lmax
data = []
for elem in dict :
    for key in elem :  # Note that only one key is there
        lst = elem[key] # z is the list
        data_curr = [np.nan] * (3*len(lmax) + 1)
        data_curr[0] = elem
        l = len(lst[0])
        for i in range(0,l) :
             data_curr[3*i+1] = z[0][i]
             data_curr[3*i+2] = z[1][i]
             data_curr[3*i+3] = z[2][i]
        data.append(data_curr]

columns = ['key','List1-1,List1-2','List1-3','List2-1','List2-2','List2-3','List3-1','List3-2','List3-3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=columns)
```

I hope you get the idea

Comment: This is not a good implementation. What happens if the requirements change to inner lists of size 1000? Are you going to code for that?

Comment: I think the OP has got the idea. we just need one more for loop that will build the data array. Wait I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Figured I share my solution anyways:

```
from numpy import nan
mess = [{40258: [['2018-07-03T14:13:41'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
 {40257: [['2018-07-03T13:47:55',
    '2018-07-03T14:21:52',
    '2018-07-04T11:56:44'],
   ['Open', 'In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party'],
   ['In Progress', 'Waiting on 3rd Party', 'In Progress']]},
 {40255: [['2018-07-03T13:12:58'], ['Open'], ['Closed']]},
 {40250: [[], [], []]}]

master = dict()
for dicto in mess:
    key = list(dicto.keys())[0]
    master[key] = {('List{}-{}'.format(j+1,i+1)): (dicto[key][j][i] if i < len(dicto[key][j]) else nan ) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)}
output = pd.DataFrame.from_records(master, columns=list(master.keys())).T
print(output.to_string())
```

Output:

```
                   List1-1              List1-2              List1-3 List2-1      List2-2               List2-3      List3-1               List3-2      List3-3
40258  2018-07-03T14:13:41                  NaN                  NaN    Open          NaN                   NaN       Closed                   NaN          NaN
40257  2018-07-03T13:47:55  2018-07-03T14:21:52  2018-07-04T11:56:44    Open  In Progress  Waiting on 3rd Party  In Progress  Waiting on 3rd Party  In Progress
40255  2018-07-03T13:12:58                  NaN                  NaN    Open          NaN                   NaN       Closed                   NaN          NaN
40250                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN     NaN          NaN                   NaN          NaN                   NaN          NaN
```